# How to pass json data to another screen that contains bottom tab navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

I am new in flutter and right now I have 2 screens, they are login screen and home screen that contains bottom tab navigator. After I press login bottom, I would like to pass json data to my Home Screen. I have already tried using this code, but I can not access and call the json data in my Home Screen, is it because my Home Screen contains bottom tab navigator? or is there a way to call that data from my bottom tab navigator?.

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BottomTab(text: my json data,),
        ));
```

and this is my bottom tab navigation code

```
class BottomTab extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BottomTabState createState() => _BottomTabState();
}

class _BottomTabState
    extends State<BottomTab> {

  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  int _index = 0;

  Widget _myList(int index) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int myindex) => setState(() => _index = myindex),
        currentIndex: index,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _myList(_index),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_index],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `BottomTab` to require this String

Do this:

```
class BottomTab extends StatefulWidget {
final String text;
BottomTab({this.text});
@override
  _BottomTabState createState() => _BottomTabState();
}
class _BottomTabState extends State<BottomTab> {
   void initState() {
    print(widget.text)
    super.initState();
   }
```

Comment: Woow, it works fine with your code, thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it :D

Comment: Hi, is there a way to access ```text``` for all tab screens?

Comment: @Wah if you want to access said `text` from multiple screens, it would be better to store this text in a more accessible/central place.
It might be better to just store the text in a Singleton or in Shared Preferences, then you won't have to pass it between screens.
Please mark the question as answered if it resolved your issue.